# Key-range RangeI-N lock compatibility in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, locking, transaction

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017#key_range_modes) states that the RangeI-N lock (Insert range, null resource lock; used to test ranges before inserting a new key into an index) is compatible with itself (see the compatibility matrix), so even though one transaction has obtained a RangeI-N lock on particular key another transaction can also obtain such a lock.

Further below, it says that

> When inserting a value within a transaction, the range the value falls
>   into does not have to be locked for the duration of the transaction
>   performing the insert operation. Locking the inserted key value until
>   the end of the transaction is sufficient to maintain serializability.
>   For example, given this INSERT statement:
>
> INSERT mytable VALUES ('Dan');
>
> The RangeI-N mode key-range lock is placed on the index entry
>   corresponding to the name David to test the range. If the lock is
>   granted, Dan is inserted and an exclusive (X) lock is placed on the
>   value Dan. The RangeI-N mode key-range lock is necessary only to test
>   the range and is not held for the duration of the transaction
>   performing the insert operation. Other transactions can insert or
>   delete values before or after the inserted value Dan. However, any
>   transaction attempting to read, insert, or delete the value Dan will
>   be locked until the inserting transaction either commits or rolls
>   back.

Quoting another [source](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233327&seqNum=3) - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals: Transactions and Concurrency:

> For example, the RangeIn-Null lock is acquired when SQL Server
>   attempts to insert into the range between keys in a session using
>   Serializable isolation. This type of lock is not often seen because it
>   is typically very transient. It is held only until the correct
>   location for insertion is found, and then the lock is converted into
>   an X lock.

My understanding is that this type of lock is during the process of identifying the range where the newly inserted key should be placed (I'm assuming that's what 'test the range' means). After this happens the lock is released, the new key gets inserted and an X lock is placed on it.

However I do not see why two RangeI-N locks are said to be compatible with each other. If transactions A and B both place a RangeI-N lock on the same key because they both want to insert a new key into the range and transaction A performs the insert first, then the location for key insertion determined by B might be already incorrect because the ranges have changed (A inserted a new value there). Could anyone explain that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding is that this type of lock is during the process of
>   identifying the range where the newly inserted key should be placed
>   (I'm assuming that's what 'test the range' means). After this happens
>   the lock is released, the new key gets inserted and an X lock is
>   placed on it.

`RangeI-N` lock is requested to test that insertion into key range will not interfere with another transaction that may potentially do some serializable operation incompatible with insertion (like reading for example).

During insertion of record into index database engine locates page, where key being inserted should be placed. Page and key locks are not used at this stage yet, only latches. Once page is located, engine starts acquiring locks necessary for performing insertion of record to the page. These are `IX` lock for the page located, then `RangeI-N` lock for the key next to key being inserted. Upon acquiring `RangeI-N` is not held, and next `X` lock for the key being inserted is requested. After necessary locks acquired, insertion of the record proceeds.

Say we have table and data

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
    K int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UQ_T UNIQUE CLUSTERED (K)
);

INSERT INTO T (K)
VALUES (1), (2), (9), (10);
```

Let's take result of the following query

```
SELECT K, %%lockres%% AS lockres
FROM T;
```

which is

```
K    lockres
---- ---------------
1    (8194443284a0)
2    (61a06abd401c)
9    (30b7763ed433)
10   (d08358b1108f)
```

(we will refer to it in the things that follow).

Then, say we have a query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T
WHERE K BETWEEN 1 AND 9;
```

Running it under `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level results to the following locking footprint

[image: SELECT locking footprint]

To protect key range, database engine locks every key in this range with `RangeS-S` lock. Additionally, key next to the range is locked (this is necessary for non-unique index, but engine is doing it for unique index too). In this case, locks are placed on resources corresponding (according to result of the query taken earlier) to keys 1, 2, 9 and 10.

Non-concurrent insertion to the table

```
INSERT INTO T (K)
VALUES (3);
```

results to following locking footprint

[image: INSERT locking footprint]

Key 3 does not exists in the table, and so database engine requests `RangeI-N` lock on the resource *(30b7763ed433)* corresponding to key 9, which is next to 3 at the moment. Acquiring `RangeI-N` means that there is no incompatible serializable activity being performed, so engine proceeds and acquires `X` lock on the resource *(98ec012aa510)* corresponding to key 3. Then actual insertion happens and locks are released. Notice that there is no release of `RangeI-N` lock.

Running above `SELECT` and `INSERT` concurrently causes `INSERT` to wait until transaction performed serializable `SELECT` is active

[image: SELECT and INSERT concurrency]

because of `RangeI-N` incompatibility with `RangeS-S`. As soon as transaction performed `SELECT` ends `INSERT` will proceed.

This is what "test the range" means.

---

> However I do not see why two RangeI-N locks are said to be compatible
>   with each other.

`RangeI-N` locks compatibility is good, because of it allows concurrent insertions into key range.

Imagine we are doing

```
INSERT INTO T (K)
VALUES (4);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO T (K)
VALUES (6);
```

concurrently.

It may happen that at some moment both statements acquire `RangeI-N` on the resource *(30b7763ed433)* corresponding to key 9. But this is fine, because of then concurrency is controlled by `X` on the keys and by page latch further.

Comment: Nice anwer, thanks you. One question about the last part - if both transactions place I-N lock on key 9, and key 6 is inserted first, then the other transaction should not insert that key just before key 9, but it now should be inserted before key 6. The original I-N protects the range from 9 to the previous key, which is now 6. Does it mean the I-N lock is placed on key 6 before 4 gets inserted?

Comment: @user4205580, the aim of RI-N is not to protect range, while insertion is performed. Its aim is formulated in first sentence of the answer. In other words, things are a kind of opposite rather. RI-N is used to test that **other** transactions do not protect range (by either of RS-S, RS-U, RX-S, RX-U or RX-X), i.e. that insertion will not break serializability of **another** transaction.

Comment: @user4205580 Essentially first part of the answer is the example of it. Serializable transaction reads 1,2,9 between 1 and 9, so it must be 1,2,9 until it ends. Without RI-N testing the range, insertion of 3 between 2,9 would break its serializability. Does things get clearer this way? Regarding 4 and 6 insertion. If transaction doing insertion of 6 placed RI-N on 9, then X on 6 and did actual insertion into page, and transaction doing insertion of 4 didn't acquired RI-N yet, then yes it will acquire RI-N on 6, because of key next to 4 is 6 at the moment (even if it is not committed).

Comment: One more question after a long delay: Notice that there is no release of RangeI-N lock - why is that the case? I understand that it's not released during transacrion, but it is released after the transaction completes?

Comment: @user4205580, there is no release of RI-N visible in the Profiler output, but I think that internally it is a kind of released or discarded immediately upon acquiring. Holding RI-N until end of transaction would be a resource waste, because of locks are held to protect something, but RI-N is not for protection, it is for testing (probing) that there is no protection.